# Is there one main master jquery file?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been looking around and it seems that there lots of different jquery library files though I was wondering whether there was one file that supported all types of jquery?

Comment: So you're looking for a jquery.js which is compatible with all released jQuery versions?

Comment: Yep cos all over you see jquery 1.10.1 or 1.9.1 or whatever and I was wondering if there was one file that addressed all

Comment: What sense would that make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't completely understand the concept of jQuery. jQuery itself is a library for javascript which gives you all kinds of functionality you can use. For jQuery there are lots of plugins. Those plugins basically are libraries that are using jQuery functions. So I don't exactly know what you mean with 'supported all types of jquery', but there is no package that includes every plugin. jQuery has different versions though (sequential, not parallel) if that is what you mean with 'types of jQuery'. This is no different though then with other programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

There are different versions of jQuery which have been released over time. Think of it like any other piece of software - there is Windows XP, Windows 7, Windows 8, etc. jQuery is the same - there is 1.9.1, 1.10.x, 2.x, etc. Each version has changes made, features improved, etc. I would recommend to try to always use the latest (2.x) unless there is a requirement that you cannot (for example, 2.x does not support IE6 anymore).

So, to specifically answer your question - no, there does not exist a roll-up of all the jQuery versions. That would be fairly impossible to work with. Pick the version that you need with a preference towards latest unless something else compels you not to.